# How to disable pickTime bootstrap dateTimePicker

Tags: bootstrap-datetimepicker, smalot-datetimepicker

I want to disable the time choice with bootstrap-datetimepicker.

This is my JavaScript:

```js
$('.dateTimePicker2').datetimepicker({
    language: "fr",
    pickTime: false,
});
```

I know that there are different datetimepicker plugins. I use smalot/bootstrap-datetimepicker. Even if I set `pickTime` to `false`, it doesn't work? Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `format` and `minView` [option](https://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/index.php), setting `format: "yyyy-mm-dd"` and `minView: "month"`. The `format` option determines the format to show in the input while the `minView` option is the *lowest view that the datetimepicker should show*.

Here a working sample:

```js
$('.dateTimePicker2').datetimepicker({
    format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
    minView: "month",
    language: "fr"
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/smalot-bootstrap-datetimepicker/2.4.4/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/smalot-bootstrap-datetimepicker/2.4.4/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/smalot-bootstrap-datetimepicker/2.4.4/js/locales/bootstrap-datetimepicker.fr.js"></script>

<input size="16" type="text" readonly class="dateTimePicker2">
```